# Integrate AWS s3 bucket with flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, amazon-s3, flutter-aws-amplify

I'm creating **flutter** application with **Firebase authentication**. But **I need to store some recording files (mp3)** to cloud storage. I need to use **aws s3 as a requirement**. So I tried to integrate the that with flutter.

I have found official plugin called [amplify_storage_s3](https://pub.dev/packages/amplify_storage_s3) on [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/amplify_storage_s3)

But I had to read from documentation I need to amplify authentication to use that.

I don't want to use amplify auth because I'm already done it with firebase authentication.

So what I can do?